# .net mvc does not auto trigger validation using iCheck.js and select2.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, icheck

in my mvc4 application,i user select2 and iCheck plugins to make form behaviours nicely, but some questions occured when validating models.

form ellments that using select2 and iCheck do not validate automatically when value changes.

but when i submit the form, validation trggered.

I want the form elements using select2 and iCheck validate automatically when value changes, just as the valdations behaviour on textbox.

**below image validation is trggered when submit the form,this is well**

[image: this validation is triggered when submit the form]

**when i select a not empty value, the error message still stay here, how to solve it?**
[image]

**it will validate when i submit the form again.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("-select2 element-").on("change",function(){
    $(this).valid();
});
```

to validate each time the element changes.